# Pandas Excel Prasing, removing strikeouts

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an `.xlsx` excel workbook where certain cells have data that contains a strike out. I would like to remove all the cells or the entire row/column containing any <s>strike-out's</s> when reading an excel sheet.

Currently with pandas, the formatting of all strike out's are removed while loading with pandas, leaving no way to differentiate data that had a strike-out or data that didn't.